# 2 dimension array to multiple 1 dimension arrays with keys

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

my array:

```
Array
(
[patient_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
            [1] => 24
            [2] => 25
        )

[fullname] => Array
    (
        [0] => Jhon Sena
        [1] => Mary Sena 
        [2] => Carter Sena
    )

[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => pdf
        [1] => pdf
        [2] => pdf
    )

[textarea_text] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => text2
        [2] => text3
        )

)
```

what i'm triying to get:

```
Array
(
    [patient_id] => 23
    [fullname] => Jhon Sena
    [type] => pdf
    [textarea_text] => text
)
Array
(
    [patient_id] => 24
    [fullname] => Mary Sena
    [type] => pdf
    [textarea_text] => text2
)    
Array
    (
    [patient_id] => 25
    [fullname] => Carter Sena
    [type] => pdf
    [textarea_text] => text3
)
```

i've been trying with many php flatten array functions pointed here in another questions but i could not get the desired results, can you please point me in the right direction?

For example this flatten function:

```
function flatten($ar) {
        $toflat = array($ar);
        $res = array();

        while (($r = array_shift($toflat)) !== NULL) {
            foreach ($r as $v) {
                if (is_array($v)) {
                    $toflat[] = $v;
                } else {
                    $res[] = $v;
                }
            }
        }

        return $res;
    }
```

Throws me this result with no keys:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 23
    [1] => 24
    [2] => 25
    [3] => Jhon Sena
    [4] => Mary Sena
    [5] => Carter Sena
    [6] => pdf
    [7] => pdf
    [8] => pdf
    [9] => text
    [10] => text2
    [11] => text3
)
```

.............................

Comment: _i've been trying with many php flatten array functions pointed here in another questions_ ->Then please post your attempted code in your question, to make us believe in you that you really tried something.

Comment: The issue is that you really aren't looking to simply flatten this. You need a custom function that builds that new array per your specification (where every numeric index in inner arrays represents an element of the same subarray in the result).

Comment: i've edited the post with an example of what i'm been doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via simple `foreach()`

```
$fialArray = [];

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $k=>$val){
        $fialArray[$k][$key] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($fialArray);
```

Output : https://3v4l.org/qqgp7

Comment: @elgranchuchu  glad to help you. Please have a look to the edited solution. It's more efficient now